# enum with generic HashMap

Tags: generics, enums, hashmap

i tried to create something like this as an enum:

```
    public final class CoCoreMemory<T>{

    public static final CoCoreMemory<CoeUser> users = new CoCoreMemory<CoeUser>();
    public static final CoCoreMemory<CoeAdmin> admins = new CoCoreMemory<CoeAdmin>();
    public static final CoCoreMemory<CoeRequest> requests = new CoCoreMemory<CoeRequest>();

    private HashMap<String, T> mem = new HashMap<String, T>();

    public int add(String zzf, T t){
        int result = -1;
        if(!mem.containsKey(zzf)) {
            mem.put(zzf, t);
            result = 100;
        }
        return result;
    }
    private CoCoreMemory(){

    }
}
```

My attempt is as follows.....

```
    public enum Memory<T>{

    <CoeUser>users, <CoeAdmin> admins, <CoeRequest> requests;

    private HashMap<String, T> mem = new HashMap<String, T>();

    public int add(String zzf, T t){
        int result = -1;
        if(!mem.containsKey(zzf)) {
            mem.put(zzf, t);
            result = 100;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Actually I just want to have a certain number of instances have its own HashMap of a certain type. But a generic enum isn't possible at all, is it?

Any other solutions to get something like this?

Comment: I've read this a couple of times, and I have no clue what you want

Comment: The lower code block doesn't work because generic enums aren't possible. I just want to have three fixed instances that have a HashMap in it with a specific Type. For Instance: I have three istances...users, admins and requests. The HashMap mem within users should only contain UserObjects, the HashMap within admins should only contain AdminObjects and the final one RequestObjects. Actually the same thing of the upper codeblock but as Enum not as Class

Answer (score 0):

Use a normal typed class with static constants for your instances, like this:

```
public class Memory<T> {
    public static final Memory<CoeUser> USERS = new Memory<CoeUser>();
    public static final Memory<CoeAdmin> ADMINS = new Memory<CoeAdmin>();
    public static final Memory<CoeRequest> REQUESTS = new Memory<CoeRequest>();

    private Map<String, T> mem = new HashMap<String, T>();

    public int add(String zzf, T t){
        int result = -1;
        if (!mem.containsKey(zzf)) {
            mem.put(zzf, t);
            result = 100;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

When you need to use them, simply:

```
int result = Memory.USERS.add("foo", myCoeUser);
```

FYI, the instances are automatically initialized when you first use the Memory class. Also, convention is that constants (ie `static final`) are named all uppercase (with underscores separating words if required)